# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'RouterElect'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, ienumerable, selectlist, viewdata

This question has been asked for similar problems before, but I'm not sure how to apply those answers to my specific problem:

**ViewModel**

```
   public string RouterElect { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
    if ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.JudgeCode)) && (Model.userIsAuthorized))
    {
        <div id="ChangeRouterSection" class="live-tile" data-mode="carousel" data-direction="vertical" data-delay="7000">
             @{Html.RenderPartial("_ChangeCurrentRouter");}
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div id="ChangeRouterSection" class="live-tile" data-mode="carousel" data-direction="vertical" data-delay="7000">
            <div class="tile">
                User not authorized. Access denied.
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

**Partial View**

```
    @model JudicialPortal.ViewModels.PortalIndexView

    <div class="tile">
        Change Current Router
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RouterElect, Model.JPortalChamberUsersAsItems, new { @id = "changeCurrentRouterInput", @class = "m-wrap", @onchange = "" })
        <button type="button" class="m-btn green-stripe" onclick="changeCurrentRouter();"
        style="color: #444; text-decoration: none;">
        Okay</button>
    </div>
```

When the Page loads it renders without problem, looking like this:

[Tile From rendered page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JkY7.png)

However when a item from the dropdown is chosen and then the OKay button is clicked the following error occurs:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'RouterElect'.

For the line of code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RouterElect, Model.JPortalChamberUsersAsItems, new { @id = "changeCurrentRouterInput", @class = "m-wrap", @onchange = "" })
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Update:
Someone asked about the JPortalChamberUsersAsItems backend code:

```
    JPortalChamberUsersAsItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["JPortalChamberUsersAsItems"] != null)
    {
        JPortalChamberUsersAsItems = HttpContext.Current.Session["JPortalChamberUsersAsItems"] as List<SelectListItem>;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tempArrayOfUsers.Count; i++)
        {
            JPortalChamberUsersAsItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = tempArrayOfUsers[i], Value = tempArrayOfUsers[i] });
        }

        foreach (SelectListItem routerUser in JPortalChamberUsersAsItems)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(routerUser.Text))
            {
                if (routerUser.Text.ToUpper() != "PLEASE SELECT A ROUTER")
                {
                    routerUser.Text = ReplaceUsernameWithFullName(routerUser.Text);
                }
            }
        }

        JPortalChamberUsersAsItems.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "Please select a router", Value = "Please select a router" })); //2014-12-15 This code adds the "default" first option - DO NOT REMOVE

        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("JPortalChamberUsersAsItems", JPortalChamberUsersAsItems);
    }
```

Another question was asked about the OKay action.  It calls the changeCurrentRouter Script, which executes the ChangeCurrrentRouter action:

```
public ActionResult ChangeCurrentRouter(string changeCurrentRouterInput, string JudgeCode, bool userIsAuthorized, PortalIndexView viewmodel)
{
    bool databaseCallOk = false;
    string errorString = "";
    viewmodel.userIsAuthorized = userIsAuthorized;
    viewmodel.JudgeCode = JudgeCode;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(changeCurrentRouterInput))
    {
        if (changeCurrentRouterInput.ToUpper() != "PLEASE SELECT A ROUTER")
        {
            //database call
            databaseCallOk = viewmodel.changeRouterUser(changeCurrentRouterInput, JudgeCode);
        }
    }

    if (databaseCallOk == false)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewmodel.errorCatcher))
        {

            errorString = "An error occurred trying to change the router for your chambers. Please confirm your selection and try again.";
            viewmodel.errorCatcher = errorString;
        }
    }

    viewmodel.justAttemptedRoutingChange = true;

    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_ChangeCurrentRouter.cshtml", viewmodel);
}
```

Comment: What is the backend code for Model.JPortalChamberUsersAsItems?

Comment: What happens when you click OKay button ? Is it submitting the form ? To which action method ? Can you share the code of the action method ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing when you click the OK button. I assume it submit a form to an action method and you are returning the posted model back to the view again on some usecase ( may be when the Model validation fails ? ). Anytime you return an object to your view, you need to make sure that you are (re)loading the `JPortalChanerUsersAsItems` collection property again. Because Http is stateless and it won't persist the value of that property between multiple requests.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(PortalIndexView model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       // to do : Save and redirect
   }
   // Reload the collection.
   // I hard coded 2 items here. But you may get it from db and use it
   model.JPortalChamberUsersAsItems = new List<SelectListItem> {
     new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="Detroit" } ,
     new SelectListItem { Value="2", Text="Ann Arbor" }
   };
   return View(model);

}
```

Comment: One thing I wanted to note the code executes w/out error on the first pass when the page is being rendered.  But when that happens the View (Index.cshtml) and its partial view (_ChangeCurrentRouter.cshtml).  The error occurs when the Okay button is clicked, and in that case only the PartialView (_ChangeCurrentRouter.cshtml) is seen in the CallStack

Comment: Put breakpoint in your action method and see whether any of your properties of the model is null.

Comment: In the action method, there are no nulls.  I'm guessing the rendering after the method is where the error is happening?